# Solve a nonlinear equation system with constraints on the variables

Tags: python, scipy

Some hypothetical example solving a nonlinear equation system with fsolve:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (x+y**2-4, math.exp(x) + x*y - 3)

x, y =  fsolve(equations, (1, 1))

print(equations((x, y)))
```

Is it somehow possible to solve it using `scipy.optimize.brentq` with some interval, e.g. [-1,1]? How does the unpacking work in that case?

Comment: brent is scalar-only. You seem to have 2 variables. So [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html#scipy.optimize.root) are your candidates. If you need bounds, you can use optimize.minimize, but need a different formulation.

Comment: That is right, I have two variables and I need bounds for each of them. Can you give an example two solve an equation system that way?

Comment: Look up the tutorial and API of scipy.optimize.minimize. It's not that hard. Try something and edit your question if there are problems.

Comment: This is a __nonlinear__ system, so I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As sascha suggested, constrained optimization is the easiest way to proceed. The [`least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) method is convenient here: you can directly pass your `equations` to it, and it will minimize the sum of squares of its components.

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
res = least_squares(equations, (1, 1), bounds = ((-1, -1), (2, 2)))
```

The structure of `bounds` is `((min_first_var, min_second_var), (max_first_var, max_second_var))`, or similarly for more variables.

The resulting object has a bunch of fields, shown below. The most relevant ones are: `res.cost` is essentially zero, which means a root was found; and `res.x` says what the root is: [ 0.62034453,  1.83838393]

```
 active_mask: array([0, 0])
        cost: 1.1745369255773682e-16
         fun: array([ -1.47918522e-08,   4.01353883e-09])
        grad: array([  5.00239352e-11,  -5.18964300e-08])
         jac: array([[ 1.        ,  3.67676787],
       [ 3.69795254,  0.62034452]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 7
        njev: 7
  optimality: 8.3872972696740977e-09
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 0.62034453,  1.83838393])
```

Comment: I totally forgot ```least_squares```, which is obviously better than the more general methods in ```minimize```!

Comment: Cheers. Assuming there are multiple roots on the interval, can you somehow display all of them?

Comment: @Peterhack That's not what those optimizers are build for. Of course you can optimize with different starting-points resulting in different local-minima if there are some... But this is tricky and quite unstable. You also need to decide on those starting-points... I begin to wonder if you should not pursue symbolic-methods here (sympy).

Comment: Ok. Can sympy solve very complex functions without doing that analytically myself or simplifying it? So basically, can I give it any crazy function with integrals, sums,...?

Comment: @Peterhack No, SymPy won't help with this one (though it may with some other systems). A random nonlinear system, or even a single equation, does not admit any analytic solution. As for numerics: if you come up with a way to reliably find all solutions of an arbitrary nonlinear system, you'll be famous.   I'd try running the `least_squares`  loop with random starting points, to see if you get substantially different `res.x` results with `res.cost` close to zero.