# How to solve a nonlinear, trivariate equation with constraints in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to minimize z equation: `z = 10.33 - 4.14*x + 1.28*y + 0.49375*x**2 - 0.35654*x*y + 0.071054*y**2`. The constraints are as follows:

```
0 <= x <= 15
0 <= y <= 15
z >= 0.1
```

I have no idea where to start. I imported numpy and scipy so far. I am having trouble defining the function and adding constraints.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

def func_ppm(x, y):
   z = 10.33 - 4.14*x + 1.28*y + 0.49375*x**2 - 0.35654*x*y + 0.071054*y**2
   return(z)

sc.optimize.minimize(func_ppm)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Pass the arguments to the `func_ppm` function as a list (and parse them appropriately in the function).
2. Pass a guess value to the `minimize` function.
3. Pass constraints (and bounds).

The code would look something like this:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def func_ppm(x_list):
   x = x_list[0]
   y = x_list[1]
   z = 10.33 - 4.14*x + 1.28*y + 0.49375*x**2 - 0.35654*x*y + 0.071054*y**2
   return(z)

bounds = [(0, 15), (0, 15)]
constraints = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:  func_ppm(x)-0.1},)

guess = [1,1]
minimize(func_ppm,guess,bounds=bounds,constraints = constraints)
```

Output:

```
     fun: 0.10000000032264289
     jac: array([ 0.26563454, -0.15630507])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully'
    nfev: 33
     nit: 11
    njev: 11
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([ 8.62741411, 11.53849878])
```

From the output, the local minimum point is `[8.62741411, 11.53849878]` and the function value at this point is `0.10000000032264289`.

So, the `x` and `y` values are `8.62741411` and `11.53849878` respectively, and the `z` value is `0.10000000032264289`

Answer (score 1):

I also didn't know how to solve this, so I took @karlKnechtel's suggestion in the comments and found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47314490/1717828) solved this way.

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
import math


def equations(p):
    x, y = p
    return (
        10.33
        - 4.14 * x
        + 1.28 * y
        + 0.49375 * x ** 2
        - 0.35654 * x * y
        + 0.071054 * y ** 2,
    )


res = least_squares(equations, (1, 1), bounds=((0, 0), (15, 15)))
res
```

which prints

```
 active_mask: array([0, 0])
        cost: 1.4873745428436964e-21
         fun: array([5.45412604e-11])
        grad: array([ 8.90491568e-13, -2.71417954e-12])
         jac: array([[ 0.01632693, -0.04976378]])
     message: '`gtol` termination condition is satisfied.'
        nfev: 113
        njev: 100
  optimality: 7.855036679972445e-12
      status: 1
     success: True
           x: array([ 8.82101186, 12.77394489])
```

[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=local%20min%20%2810.33%20-%204.14*x%20%2B%201.28*y%20%2B%200.49375*x**2%20-%200.35654*x*y%20%2B%200.071054*y**2%29%20%20%2C%20%7Bx%2C0%2C15%7D%2C%20%7By%2C0%2C15%7D) seems to have trouble finding this same answer to back up the results, but the plot looks like the minimum is around 9, 12, so I think it's on the right track.

Comment: But according to the problem statement, the `z` value, i.e., the function value, should be greater than or equal to `0.1`

Comment: Also, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html . I played around with this too and got result=1.44 if I recall, but before including the constraints. Also used a lambda as in the bottom example on the page. The doc shows required arguments and everything.