# Solve equations for exponent in python

Tags: python, equation, exponent

This code solves for the exponent in x^n + y^n - z^n = 0 by brute force.  Would there be a faster and cleaner way to do this?

```
import math
for n in range(-10, 100000000):
    n /= 1000000.0   
    x =  16**(n)+20**(n)-25**(n)  #formula to solve must equal zero
    if round(x,2) == 0:
        print('exponent is: ',n, ', error is: ',x); break
```

Comment: Maybe using SageMath --> https://www.sagemath.org/ . It allows you to define equations with multiple variables and get the result. But Sage takes some time to get installed - I don't know if it's in the scope of your question ?

Comment: @LucasD.Meier Thanks for your answer, I'll check that out.  WolframAlpha works well too, but I'm trying to keep this in my python library.

Comment: Ok ok. Yes, sagemath is based on Python. I use it as a separate kernel/environment. Then you can install any additional pip packages directly in the sage environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your function that should be minimized (in your case equal to zero):

```py
def f(n):
    return 16**(n) + 20**(n) - 25**(n)
```

and then import `minimize_scalar` from `scipy.optimize` and solve your equation for `n`.

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar

minimize_scalar(f)

-------------------------------
fun: 0.0
nfev: 55
nit: 35
success: True
x: -518.3839114719358 # x is your n that solves your equation
-------------------------------
```

Check:

```py
f(-518.3839114719358) # -> 0.0
```

Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html) for more. There are additional options you can give the function (like bounds). You also can access each output value (like `x`, `niter`, and so on). Besides, the computation really is a no-timer.

Comment: But, my equation solution from brute force is 2.156497 (?)

Comment: @gerald, but you are not iterating over the whole universe. Currently, you are iterating from -10/1000000.0 to 100000000/1000000.0.

Comment: @gerald, btw. you can also use `math.isclose(x, 0, abs_tol=1e-10)` to check whether two values are close.

Comment: @gerald, if you want to minimize your function in a certain range, you could use `least_squares` from `scipy.optimize`. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312188/solve-a-nonlinear-equation-system-with-constraints-on-the-variables) for more information.